# Dialectic of Enlightment Prerequisites

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, adorno, horkheimer

I wanted to start reading *Dialectic of Enlightenment* by Adorno and Horkheimer. My question is simple: Which philosophers' works do I have to be familiar with to get a decent first time reading from it?

Also on a similar note, is this a book that can be manageable and fruitful for someone as an undergrad?

Comment: Kant, Hegel, Freud...

Comment: See [Adorno](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/adorno/#2) and [Horkheimer](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/horkheimer/#CriReaDomNat).

Comment: The first long essay requires some familiarity with Homers Odessey.

Comment: In the larger context, Marx! I wouldn't be ashamed to get an intro or summary guide. Some people love Adorno, I join Kolokowski in finding him an obscurantist.

Answer (score 1):

I think the text would be challenging to an undergraduate unless a lecturer provided context and exegesis. Some philosophical texts, such as Descartes' Meditations and Locke's Essay concerning Human Understanding, can with some degree of success be tackled head-on. Others, such as Hegel's Phenomenology and Heidegger's Being and Time, can't. While I wouldn't put Adorno and Horkheimer in the same league as Hegel and Heidegger, the same point applies to A & H.

**Odyssey**

Plainly this is a vital point of reference :

> Dialektik der Aufklärung a seminal text in twentieth-century intellectual
>    history, at the heart of which lies a mournful reading of the Odyssey. Odysseus and the
>    adventures of his voyage home provide Horkheimer and Adorno with critical material
>    for exploring the history and nature of barbarous enlightenment and their - seemingly
>    paradoxical - thesis: namely, that myth is already enlightenment; and that enlighten
>    ment reverts to mytholology. (Katie Fleming, 'Odysseus and Enlightenment: Horkheimer and Adorno's "Dialektik der Aufklärung"',  International Journal of the Classical Tradition, Vol. 19, No. 2 (JUNE 2012), pp.
>   107-128 : 107.)

**The German philhellenic tradition**

Fleming again :

> ... closer attention ought to be paid to
>    the authors' choice and interpretation of the Odyssey. Dialektik der Aufklärung is, this
>    article shall suggest, a confrontation with the German philhellenic tradition itself,
>    from Hegel to Wilamowitz, out of which arises a powerful, ethical statement about the
>    nature of that tradition, and the politics and cultural identity in which it plays a central part. (Ibid.)

**Hegel and Nietzsche**

Special mention should be made of these two. Adorno and Horkheimer contrast their positions within the philhellenic tradition :

> It is important to note, however, that here and particularly in his later work, Der
>    Antichrist (1888), Nietzsche does not follow Hegel, whose philosophical programme
>    ultimately justifies Christianity. In this respect their appropriations of antiquity
>    differ dramatically. For Hegel, the Greeks are proto-Christians. For Nietzsche, Griechentum [Hellenism : GT] is opposed to Christianity (which he places in the same negative category as
>    archaic Judaism).

But Adorno and Horkheimer's discussion of Hegel and Nietzsche is too complex to summarise adequately here.